# How to avoid Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error when hitting a Django API from another server process?

Tags: python, django, node.js, cors, django-cors-headers

I am building a WebApp that has two separate components:

1. A "frontend" node.js application server (running on localhost:3099) that web-visitors will visit
2. A "backend" Django server (running on localhost:3098) that manages my ORM and talks to the database. Web visitors will not interact with this server directly at all. This server simply publishes a RESTful API that will be consumed by the frontend.

I will implement security restrictions that will prevent anyone except the frontend server from accessing the backend's API.

One of the API endpoint the backend publishes looks like this: `http://localhost:3098/api/myApi/`.

I can successfully hit that API from curl like so: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"myKey1":"myVal1", "myKey2":"myVal2"}' http://localhost:3098/api/myApi/`

However, when I try to hit that same API from my frontend server using Javascript, I get the following error in my browser's console window:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3098/api/myApi/. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3099' is therefore not allowed access.
```

To solve this, took the following steps:

1. I installed [**django-cors-headers**](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)
2. I added `'corsheaders'` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. I added `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` above `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'`
4. I declared the whitelist: `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('localhost', '127.0.0.1',)`

However, implementing django-cors-headers seems to have made no difference. I'm still getting the same CORS error. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is port-sensetive. [Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-4) says that

```
If there is no port component of the URI:
1.  Let uri-port be the default port for the protocol given by uri-scheme.
Otherwise:
2.  Let uri-port be the port component of the URI.
```

And

> If the two origins are scheme/host/port triples, the two origins are the same if, and only if, they have identical schemes, hosts, and ports.

This means that, with your spec CORS handles your whitelist as `localhost:80, 127.0.0.1:80`. I believe specifying `localhost:3099` should resolve this issue.